# problems understanding conditions in if statement python

Tags: python

Hello i am a beginner in python programming and  I have to write a rock paper scissor game. However the only strings that should be typed in are rock, scissor or paper. if i check them in an if statement  i have the following problem The code above keeps on giving correct as output even though I put wrong input in player1 and player2.
It does not switch to the else condition.

```
def rps():
print "********** Rock Paper Scissors **********"

print 'what does player 1 choose?' 
player1 = raw_input()
print 'what does player 2 choose?' 
player2 = raw_input()

if player1 and player2 == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissor':
    print 'correct'

else:
    print 'this is not a valid object selection'
```

and the weird thing is that in some cases it actually does work?

Answer (score 2):

It's a valid expression, just doesn't do what you might think it does:

```
if player1 and player2 == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissor':
```

is checking several things:

```
player
player2 == 'rock'
'paper'
'scissor'
```

A string is convertible to bool if its non-empty. So in this case `'paper'` and `'scissor'` both evaluate as `True`. Thus, we can rewrite your condition as the following, adding parenthesis for emphasis:

```
if  (player1 and player2 == 'rock') or True or True:
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if True:
```

Probably not what you want to check.

Comment: Thank you for your help i did not know that a string will convert to a bool is its non empty. Great answer and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement reads:

```
if player1 and player2 == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissor':
```

Python allows you to omit parentheses, but this is how it is parsed:

```
if (player1) and (player2 == 'rock') or ('paper') or ('scissor'):
```

Meaning, it checks for the truthiness of player1, whether player2 is 'rock', or whether 'paper' or 'scissor' are truthy.

In Python, a non-empty string is always truthy meaning 'paper' or 'scissor' will always be `True`.

What you actually want is something like

```
if player1 in ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor') and player2 in ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor')
```

Comment: Thank you i did not no that python parses this in another way!